# how to convert double values to integer with int fint (double) without getting 'Server connection lost' in Uppaal

Tags: integer, double, uppaal

I want to convert double values to integer to use them in the guards of the model.For this I found the **int fint (double)** function at https://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/download.shtml and now I use uppaal-4.1.24 instead of uppaal-4.1.19. Unfortunately I always get the message **'Server connection lost'** when I try to execute the corresponding transition in one of the simulators or in the verifier. Has anyone had a similar problem and knows a solution?

Best greetings,
Josi

Comment: I wanted to do exactly the same yesterday and got the same problem. I opened an issue there: https://github.com/UPPAALModelChecker/UPPAAL-Meta/issues
I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Uppaal 4.1.24 simulators are not able to handle floating point variables (and models with ODEs). These features currently for only in verifier using SMC queries.

See issue 23 for more details:
https://github.com/UPPAALModelChecker/UPPAAL-Meta/issues/23